# Haskell (nested) ReaderT

Tags: haskell, monads

how can you access the inner monad of a ReaderT.

In my case I have the typ:

```
newtype VCSSetupAction a = VCSSetupAction (ReaderT (Maybe VCSConf) IDEM a)
    deriving (Monad, MonadIO, MonadReader (Maybe VCSConf))
```

I cann access the (Maybe VCSConf) in a function running in this Monad like

```
commitAction' :: Common.VCSAction ()
commitAction' = do
   config <- ask
   ...
```

but I should also be able to access the inner IDEM which turns out to be of type:

```
type IDEM = ReaderT IDERef IO
```

so I want to be able to do something like

```
commitAction' :: Common.VCSAction ()
commitAction' = do
   config <- ask
   ideRef <- lift $ ask -- this does not compile/work
```

I still do not understand Monads well enough for this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `lift` directly, your `newtype` would have to derive `MonadTrans`, but since it's not a transformer, this is not appropriate in this case. Instead, you can just wrap the action in your data constructor. Now you're dealing directly with the `ReaderT`, so you can use its `lift`.

```
ideRef <- VCSSetupAction $ lift $ ask
```

You might want to define a helper for this to make things cleaner.